# How to get parameter function javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

how to set and get parameter value?
I have function like this:

```
var File = function(){
  "use strict";
   var readFile = function(element){
     console.log(element);  //i want get paramater here
   }

   return {
     init:function(){readFile()}
   }
}();
```

and i implement this function like:

```
File.init('#image');
```

but i still get ***undefined***

Comment: The `init` method has no parameter, and doesn't pass anything to `readFile()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You almost got this. Try something like this instead:

```js
var File = function(){
  "use strict";
   var readFile = function(element){
     console.log(element);  //i want get paramater here
   }

   return {
     init: function(element){ readFile(element) }
   }
}();

File.init('#element');
```

Answer (score 1):

You are defining your `init` as a function that takes no parameter. You should make `init` a function that takes an element as a parameter and uses it to call `readFile`.

```
var File = function(){
  "use strict";
   var readFile = function(element){
     console.log(element);  //i want get paramater here
   }

   return {
     init:function(element){
         readFile(element);
     }
   }
}();
```

**Side note:** a probably more organized way of writing your code is to use a class called `File` that has the required functionality:

```
class File {
  static readFile(element) {
    console.log(element);
  }
  //other functions you may need here....
}

File.readFile(document.querySelector('p'));
```